# FORM won't submit even though input fields are not empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

it wont submit even though the fields are not empty

**here's the form:**

```
<form id="form" role="form" method='POST' action="user_add-post.php">
     <div class="form-group">
        <p><label class="control-label">Title</label><br />
            <input style="width: 40%" class="form-control" type="text" name="postTitle"/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <p><label lass="control-label">Description</label><br />
           <textarea name="postDesc" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <p><label>Content</label></p>
           <textarea name="postCont" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
     </div>
     <input type='submit' name="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value='Submit'></form>
```

**and here's my jquery to check if the input fields are empty:**

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($.trim($("#postTitle").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#postDesc").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#postCont").val()) === "") {
    alert('All fields required');
    return false;
}  });
```

now why won't it submit? it keeps on saying that all fields are required even though I already fill up the fields.

Comment: check for JS error in the JS console.

Comment: please give IDs to all inputs

Comment: you are using jquery selector with ids but your elements dont have ids :P see http://jsfiddle.net/gftntvrL/

Answer (score 2):

You have missed to add id in input boxes,

```
<input style="width: 40%" class="form-control" type="text" name="postTitle"/>
```

Change it to

```
<input style="width: 40%" class="form-control" type="text" id="postTitle" name="postTitle"/>
```

for next text box aswell ,Please [Refer](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You have not given the ids to any of your form field, use global selector with condition 
here is the [working fiddle of your task](http://jsfiddle.net/ccrurLtn/)

```
`$("input[name=postTitle]").val()` //name selector instead of id
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not have define the ids so change the condition to

```
if ($.trim($('[name="postTitle"]').val()) === "" || $.trim($('[name="postDesc"]').val()) === "" || $.trim($('[name="postCont"]').val()) === "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If condition should be like this:

```
if ($("#postTitle").val().trim() == "" || $("#postDesc").val().trim() == "" || $("#postCont").val().trim() == "") {
```

Answer (score 0):

See for any JS errors if you are getting. Also , try it on various browsers. You are not using ID attribute, but Name attritute, so it may not work on Firefox,Chrome and may work on IE7 and below. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Provide Id to input element in html code.

Jquery code is fine

here is the correct code of html

```
<input style="width: 40%" class="form-control" type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes like everyone else is saying if you are going to use selectors then you need those id's on the form fields.  Or you can use the names like this:

```
$("[name=postTitle]").val()
$("[name=postDesc]").val()
$("[name=postCont]").val()
```

Here is your jquery with the above:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
if ($("[name=postTitle]").val().trim() == "" || $("[name=postDesc]").val().trim() == "" || $("[name=postCont]").val().trim() == "") {
    alert('All fields required');
    return false;
}  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the selectors are based on ID but using *name* attribute values. So you can add ID attributes, change the selector or use a different strategy.

Since the listener is on the form, *this* within the function references the form and all form controls with a name are available as named properties of the form. So you can easily test the value contains something other than whitespace with a regular expression, so consider:

```
var form = this;
var re = /^\s*$/;

if (re.test(form.postTitle.value) || re.test(form.postDesc.value) || re.test(form.postCont.value) {

  /* form is not valid */

}
```

which is a lot more efficient than the OP.

Given the above, a form control with a name of *submit* will mask the form's submit method so you can't call `form.submit()` or `$('#formID').submit()`.